# COMPOSITION [10 letter answer]

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry

The works and titles of this painter were recently unveiled at an exhibition. **What ten letters did the Germans use to describe his collective of artists?**

[image: puzzle content]

*errata: the final image should be this:*
[image]

Comment: Message for question author (please ignore if you're not the OP): rot13(Url, V abgvprq gung lbh ner cbfgvat lbhe chmmyrf gb e/CvpgherTnzr nf jryy. Guvf pna yrnq gb crbcyr nppvqragnyyl fcbvyvat gur fbyhgvba sbe gurzfryirf (sbe rknzcyr, ol frnepuvat vg hc). Vg'f avpr gb frr gung lbhe chmmyrf ner ernpuvat zhygvcyr pbzzhavgvrf, ohg V jbaqre vs gurer'f n jnl gb oevat gurfr pbzzhavgvrf gbtrgure. Arkg gvzr, qb lbh guvax lbh pna cbfg chmmyrf ba qvssrerag cyngsbezf *fvzhygnarbhfyl* naq vasbez rnpu cyngsbez bs gur cerfrapr bs lbhe bgure cbfg(f)? Yrg zr xabj jung lbh guvax.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key insight is to realize that

> the shapes represent a phonetic substitution cipher

with

> angles of pink circles corresponding to vowels, large circles corresponding to consonants, and red triangles marking the start/ends of words:
>  [image]

The flavortext is

> a quote from Wassily Kandinsky

which

> allows us to assign words/phrases to each of the parts

Putting all of this together, the first 4 parts can be interpreted like so:

> [image]

Using this information, we can then interpret the last part:

> [image]

Then,

> We get the cluephrase ECHO CHAMBER OR ACT HOMOEROTIC

Which resolves to our final answer of

> CIRCLEJERK!

Comment: hi! great work so far. unfortunately there's an error i've made with the puzzle's image. [here's an updated version](https://i.imgur.com/tyYzvFz.png), changes are the >!homoerotic error as you've pointed out!<, and the left piece has been updated.

good luck!

Comment: wonderful! great job :D